# Is there a way to skip an isset() check in an if clause?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

Considering the following code:

```php
if (isset($array['key']) && $array['key'] == 'some value') {
    // do something...
} else {
    // do something else...
}
```

Is there a way I can simplify the code so that I don't have to check with isset every time I want to use an array value in an if clause? Something like `$array['key'] ?= 'some value'`

Comment: How about the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)? `if (($array['key'] ?? '') == 'some value')`

Comment: @billyonecan I never know that it can be use like that `if (($var ?? '') == 'check')`. Thank you. :)